# May one tour the Acropolis in Athens, Greece?

Tags: avodah-zarah, travel, archaeology, greek

The Acropolis with its Parthenon is Greece's #1 tourist attraction. Are there any halachic issues with touring the ruins of pagan temples?

Comment: related: [Is one allowed to visit a temple or place of worship of a religion no longer in existence?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67534/11501) and [Visiting sites previously used for idol worship](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43567/11501)

Comment: @mbloch, this seems to me to be a duplicate of those (of either of them, really, and certainly in combination). Do you agree? J G, do those pages answer your question? If not, can you [edit] the latter to indicate what's still missing?

Comment: @msh210 I do agree indeed, the only reason I didn't flag is that I'm not exactly sure of the classification of whatever ancient Greek religion was practiced there

Comment: @mbloch, considering that the actual question asks about "pagan temples", I've closed it as a duplicate. J G, again, if you're asking something different from what's on those pages, please [edit] to clarify what, and this post can be reopened to answerers.

Comment: Yes, i'm not asking anything different unless somehow Greek mythology is different than Mayan paganism.

Comment: You can actually go into the parthenon there, just walk around it outside. To go in you have to go to Nashville TN